# Troubleshooting Basic Authentication Issue

Tags: c#, httpclient, basic-authentication

I am currently working on a WinForms application using C# programming language in .NET framework 4.8.1. During my development process, I came across a useful [server](https://httpbin.org) called *https://httpbin.org* that allows anyone to practice sending requests. However, I'm encountering difficulties with `basic authentication`. Despite my efforts, I consistently receive an "401 Unauthorized" response. Even after multiple attempts, I have not been able to achieve success.

To ensure best practices, I have declared the `HttpClient` globally. Additionally, I have opted to use `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` instead of default headers, as I came across information suggesting this approach.

The `HttpResponseMessage`, named "response," displays the following headers:

- Connection: keep-alive
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
- Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
- Date: Tue, 16 May 2023 16:53:05 GMT
- Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
- **WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Fake Realm"** (← as expected once)

`responseString` is empty.

I am seeking assistance in identifying the mistake I may be making. Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you.

```
private const string Endpoint = "https://httpbin.org";
private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
```

```
string result = await Task.Run(() => CallApiAuthAsync(Endpoint + "/basic-auth/user/passwd", "username", "password"));
```

```
private string CallApiAuthAsync(string url, string username, string password)
    {
        string responseString = null;
        System.Text.Encoding Ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;

        using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
        {
             Method = HttpMethod.Get,
             RequestUri = new Uri(url),
             Headers =
             {
                 { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Ascii.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")) },
                 { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml" }
             }
        })
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = Client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result)
            {
                responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        return responseString;
    }
```

PS: I call the function itself asynchronously, not "SendAsync" and "ReadAsStringAsync" because I ran into a deadlock with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username/password you are passing in to the Web Request are incorrect:

> ```
> string result = await Task.Run(() => CallApiAuthAsync(Endpoint + "/basic-auth/user/passwd", "username", "password"));
> ```

From what I understand of the Website, you specify the username and password you want to authenticate with via the Url... `/user/passwd`. In your case, you should use `user` as username and `passwd` for the password.

Change your code to be:

```
string result = await Task.Run(() => CallApiAuthAsync(Endpoint + "/basic-auth/user/passwd", "user", "passwd"));
```

And you should see that you get an `authenticated: true` response.

I did a quick test with the site using Firefox (as well as using your C# code):

[image]

Comment: I see! It must be exactly these strings. I thought I could send any strings, but the error would be somewhere else in the code. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel good to read that it works for you. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted to help others if they need it.